# How to extract data of work items in Azure Devops to Excel

Tags: excel, azure-devops, data-extraction, azure-devops-extensions

I have a list of work items which contain some data in Description, Acceptance Criteria and Test steps. Is there a way I can extract that data and place it in an Excel spreadsheet ?

I installed Azure DevOps Office integration 2019 and grouped the work items using query. Then when I click on export to Excel, I get the data about the grouped work items, like Assigned to, work item type etc.

What I want instead is the data in those work items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can extract that data and place it in an Excel spreadsheet ?

Yes. You can add the required columns(e.g. Description, Steps) when you running the Query in Azure DevOps.

For example:

[image]

Then when you export to excel, it will show required fields.